# Can an Indian in the UK on a tourist visa apply there for a Schengen visa?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, schengen-visas

One of my contacts is in the UK right now on tourist visa which has 6 months validity. He wants to travel to Europe and, for that, he needs a Schengen visa. Can he apply from within the UK, or he has to apply from his country of residence?

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that one must apply for Schengen visas *in one's county of residence*. Being in the UK on a tourist trip doesn't make your acquaintance a resident there, so ordinarily he wouldn't be allowed to file a visa application there.

The consulates are allowed to consider visa application from non-resident, if he can provide a **good and convincing reason** why he couldn't apply from his home country. Simply wanting to go on a pleasure trip won't cut it; a suddenly arising emergency or business need might well do.